# php DomDocument + directly access xml element

Tags: php, dom, xml-parsing, domdocument

Can anyone advise on the fastest, least resource intensive method by which I can see whether 'Column Name=Error' exists please?

I don't want to parse the document, but simply check if elements exist.

Thanks in advance,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Table>
<Columns Items="4">
<Column Name="Error" Type="String" />
<Column Name="Description" Type="String" />
<Column Name="Cause" Type="String" />
<Column Name="Resolution" Type="String" />
</Columns>
<Rows Items="1">
<Row Error="2" Description="Unknown key" Cause="Unknown key" Resolution="Please check     the key is correct, it should be the in form AA11-AA11-AA11-AA11." />
</Rows>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the least resource intensive would be a simple `strpos()` call, though that's subject to error if the exact format of the XML ever changes. A fullproof way is to use DOM, then you could try an xpath query ...

```
$xml = '...'
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// returns NULL if no columns found with name="error"
$err = $xpath->query('//Column[@Name="Error"]')->item(0);

if ($err) {
  // there is a column with attribute Name="Error"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you thought of simply using `strpos`?

```
$xml= //xml data

if(strpos($xml,'<Column Name="Error"') !== false){
    // its been found
}
```

edit: added `!==false` to allow for the 0 index situation (which shouldnt happen here anyways)